# Circular dependency between resources. Cognito - lambda trigger

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-cloudformation, amazon-cognito

I have a SAM template that was working fine until I added a trigger to my cognito user pool.

I searched about the error that is throwing me: `Circular dependency between resources` I can understand that the trigger is creating a reference to the user pool and then the circular dependency arises, but ***I can not find how to solve the problem***. I only need to set the trigger of my cognito user pool to get custom messages/emails when a user is created.

This is my SAM code:

```
 AdminCognitoUserPool:
    Type: AWS::Cognito::UserPool
    Properties:
      AutoVerifiedAttributes:
        - email
      VerificationMessageTemplate: 
          DefaultEmailOption: CONFIRM_WITH_LINK
      Policies:
        PasswordPolicy:
          MinimumLength: 8
      UsernameAttributes:
        - email
      Schema:
        - AttributeDataType: String
          Name: email
          Required: true
          Mutable: true
        - AttributeDataType: String
          Name: id
          # Required: false
          Mutable: true

  AdminCognitoChangePassword:
    Type: AWS::Serverless::Function
    Properties:
      Handler: src/handlers/config.customCognitoEvents
      Role: !GetAtt lambdaRole.Arn
      Events:
        CognitoEvent:
          Type: Cognito
          Properties:
            UserPool: !Ref AdminCognitoUserPool
            Trigger: CustomMessage
```

Comment: Can you post the transformed cloudformation template?  It would be easier to see how to resolve the issue.

Answer (score 1):

The problem was in the globals function environment variables. I was calling `AdminCognitoUserPool` and thats why the circular dependency was rising.